# Is orange juice still healthy for me, if it's been opened and hasn't been refrigerated for an entire day?

Tags: diet, vitamin-c

I'm trying to take in more Vitamin C lately, and I buy a quart of cold orange juice in the morning to start my day.  It's usually sealed up - I'm guessing to keep it protected from oxygen.  But once I remove the seal and start drinking from it, I have about a half bottle left of the juice, which I then carry around with me during the day -- and I don't keep it in a refrigerator.

Is the orange juice still nutritious, after being opened and sitting around for an entire day without being kept chilled?

Comment: Why don't you just eat fruit?

Comment: You're drinking 440 calories worth of sugar per day. I wouldn't call that nutritious.

Answer (score -2):

At a recent, local science expo some high school kids did research on effects of oxidisation reducing Vit. C content over time.

Their results (and OK, not 100% authoritative) were that the Vit. C concentration actually increased even beyond the point that fruit went bad and were inedible.

So I myself would drink it with the confidence it still has health benefits.

In fact, recently I increased my Vit. C intake to 2000 mg per day, on the first hand advice of someone who took at that level to reduce cholesterol.  He said he saw reduction in this after seven days, using a commercial cholesterol tester.  2000 mg is a lot of oranges, about 20.  Need to go to vitamin pills to get that high level.  But don't forego the whole orange (or full fibre orange juice) if doing that, there is other good nutrition in the whole fruit too

Comment: Sorry but you'll need to provide a link for non obvious answers.

Comment: OK - I'll look for the student project at the Science Expo, September 2017

Comment: Reliable references are required for these sorts of answers, @Alexanderson

Comment: I'll see if the student allowed the Expo to publish his poster on their website.  Some time.